# Docker image creation failed because of userhandling

Tags: docker, docker-build

I have the following Docker File from [IMX](https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-docker).

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Update system and add the packages required for Yocto builds.
# Use DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive, to avoid image build hang waiting
# for a default confirmation [Y/n] at some configurations.

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo \
    gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 \
    python3-pip python3-pexpect xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping \
    libsdl1.2-dev xterm tar locales net-tools rsync sudo vim curl

# Set up locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
    update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# Yocto needs 'source' command for setting up the build environment, so replace
# the 'sh' alias to 'bash' instead of 'dash'.
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s bash /bin/sh

# Install repo
ADD https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/repo

# Add your user to sudoers to be able to install other packages in the container.
ARG USER
RUN echo "${USER} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/${USER} && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}

# Set the arguments for host_id and user_id to be able to save the build artifacts
# outside the container, on host directories, as docker volumes.
ARG host_uid \
    host_gid
RUN groupadd -g $host_gid nxp && \
    useradd -g $host_gid -m -s /bin/bash -u $host_uid $USER

# Yocto builds should run as a normal user.
USER $USER

# Add user git info
RUN git config --global user.name "ccisn"
RUN git config --global user.email "ccisn@hslu.ch"
RUN git config --list

RUN mkdir /home/ccisn
RUN mkdir /home/ccisn/yocto_imx8

COPY . /imx-docker


# docker run --rm -ti -v  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dockers:imx 

ARG DOCKER_WORKDIR
WORKDIR ${DOCKER_WORKDIR}
```

If I build the image via Docker Desktop it gives me folliwng error messages:

```
 => ERROR [ 8/16] RUN echo "${USER} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/${USER} &&     chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}    

------
 > [ 8/16] RUN echo "${USER} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/${USER} &&     chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}:
#12 0.483 /bin/sh: /etc/sudoers.d/: Is a directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c echo "${USER} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/${USER} &&     chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}]: exit code: 1

 *  The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command docker build --pull --rm -f "imx-docker\Dockerfile" -t dockers:imx "imx-docker"" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I dont know where the problem is. Or how I could fix it. Unfortunately I cannot use the docker image as root (since the application does not let me use it as root). Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile expects a name to be passed as a build argument.  When you build it, you need to pass that name

```bash
docker build --build-arg USER=somename .
```

A better approach might be to just delete these two lines.  You say you aren't supposed to be root inside the container, but allowing passwordless `sudo` effectively gives anyone root permissions so long as they ask politely.  You rarely install packages inside a running container since they'll be lost as soon as the container exits.  And if you do need to be root for some reason, you can launch the container with `docker run -u root`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David, you are partly right. He expects the user passed into

on the line

```
ARG USER
```

But he also takes the local defined one in (which in Windows is not defined)

```
USER $USER
```

It would be perfect to added all those needed information in hardcoded fashion (since I only need it for a build)

```
ARG USER=ccisn
ARG UID=1001
ARG GID=1001
ARG PW=ccisn
```

Then it works. But I could add all those information into ARG Statements and pass them during the build step.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Update system and add the packages required for Yocto builds.
# Use DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive, to avoid image build hang waiting
# for a default confirmation [Y/n] at some configurations.

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo \
    gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 \
    python3-pip python3-pexpect xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping \
    libsdl1.2-dev xterm tar locales net-tools rsync sudo vim curl

# Set up locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
    update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# Yocto needs 'source' command for setting up the build environment, so replace
# the 'sh' alias to 'bash' instead of 'dash'.
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s bash /bin/sh

# Install repo
ADD https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/repo

# Add your user to sudoers to be able to install other packages in the container.

ARG USER=ccisn
ARG UID=1001
ARG GID=1001
ARG PW=ccisn

RUN echo "${USER} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/${USER} && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}

# Set the arguments for host_id and user_id to be able to save the build artifacts
# outside the container, on host directories, as docker volumes.
RUN groupadd -g $GID nxp && \
    useradd -g $GID -m -s /bin/bash -u $UID $USER

# Yocto builds should run as a normal user.
# USER $USER
USER ${UID}:${GID}
# Add user git info
RUN git config --global user.name "ccisn"
RUN git config --global user.email "ccisn@hslu.ch"
RUN git config --list

RUN mkdir /home/ccisn/yocto_imx8

COPY . /imx-docker
RUN cd imx-docker/ && sudo ln -sf imx-5.10.72-2.2.0/env.sh env.sh

# docker run --rm -ti -v  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dockers:imx 

ARG DOCKER_WORKDIR
WORKDIR ${DOCKER_WORKDIR}
```